# How can i Separate my Google Analytics of the same domain if i use masking URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

So i have website abc.com, one of the section is for donuts so the url is abc.com/donuts

i bought a separate domain called donuts.com that when typed, redirect and change the url to abc.com/donuts

how can i get my analytics for donuts.com on its own in analytics but without taking it away from the normal abc.com?

i created a separate property for abc.com/donuts and analytics gave me different number for tracking code, it said "if you already have a Global Site Tag on your page, simply add the config line from the snippet below to your existing Global Site Tag."

I'm assuming this is referring to the fact that abc.com already has the analytics code so all i did was append the

```
  gtag('config', 'UA-42188401-9');
```

part from the abc.com/donuts property and append it to the abc.com analytics code

is that the proper way to do it?

when i look into my realtime data i see the realtime analytics for donuts.com and abc.com is different

is this the right way to do it? or maybe i should use segment and specify i want only user whose landing page is abc.com/donuts? since dontus.com is just masking domain>

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways:

- use one tracker for both domains and create separate views using filters by URL
- use different trackers: one on abc.com (excl. abc.com/donuts) and one on page abc.com/donuts

Comment: i dont see any options to filter by URL?

Comment: @wswswswsws  May be you don't have permissions. Filters are in View Settings.